# How can i add variables to my List by reading the User Input?

Tags: c#, list, console

Im a Beginner in C#, and would like to add to my List via. reading the Input of the User.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<int> list = new List<int>();


        Console.WriteLine("Asking a random Question here");

        // lacking Knowledge here **
         ** = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add multiple items to your list or do you just have one line of input?

Comment: @rivanov multiple items, i want a little Console Application to collect a List of Numbers and then calculate the average.

Comment: see my answer below @Dovah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for the sake of a detailed example to the question here's a program that will average the numbers listed in standard input, one per line. It shows how to add a given number to the list as well.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    namespace AverageNumbers
    {
        class MainClass
        {
            public static void Main (string[] args)
            {
                // Here is the list of numbers
                List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

                // Here are two variables to keep track
                // of the input number (n), and the sum total (sum)
                int n, sum = 0;
                // This while loop waits for user input and converts
                // that input to an integer
                while (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out n))
                {
                    // Here we add the entered number to the sum
                    sum += n;
                    // And to the list to track how many we've added       
                    numbers.Add(n);
                }

                // Finally we make sure that we have more than 0 numbers that we're summing and write out their average
                Console.WriteLine("Average: " + (numbers.Count > 0? sum / numbers.Count : 0));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your Help! I really appreciate you taking your Time!

Comment: @Dovah, no problem, ask questions if some of the lines don't make sense.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want

```
list.Add(Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()));
```

`int` is a 32 bit number and corresponds to `System.Int32`;

Comment: Im getting an Synthax Error, because " )expected" :/

Answer (score 1):

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();


    Console.WriteLine("Asking a random Question here");

    // lacking Knowledge here **
     ** = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

The Console.ReadLine() method does return a string value, in your case you want to add the value of the user input to your int list.

So basically you have to:

```
Int32 number = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

And then add the number to your list as follows:

```
list.Add(number);
```

Answer (score 0):

// You can also this

List <int list = Console.ReadLine().Select(arTemp => Convert.ToInt32(arTemp)).ToList();

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).